# How to get the previous row value in the result set of type forward only using Java

Tags: java

Id  UserName    FirstName   Surname     TimeRegistered
...........................................................
3   dsmith      David       Smith       2008-04-02 18:16:22
4   ntroberts   Nigel       Roberts     2008-05-01 20:11:01
6   bgsmithers  Bill        Smith       2008-05-02 02:43:52

```
 ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
    try {
      while (rs.next()) {
        int id = rs.getInt("Id");
        String userName = rs.getString("UserName");
        String firstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
        String surname = rs.getString("Surname");
       //How to get the previous row value usning resultset of type forward only.
        Timestamp prevtimeReg = rs.getTimestamp("TimeRegistered");

        Timestamp nexttimeReg= rs.getTimestamp("TimeRegistered");

      }
    } finally {
      rs.close();
    }
```

Comment: You store it in a variable, and read that variable at the next iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use it like:

```
Timestamp prevtimeReg = null;
while (rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt("Id");
    String userName = rs.getString("UserName");
    String firstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
    String surname = rs.getString("Surname");
    Timestamp nexttimeReg= rs.getTimestamp("TimeRegistered");
    //do your operation with previous time stamp
    Timestamp prevtimeReg = nexttimeReg;
 }
```

You assume for first row you dont have any previous time stamp. Then when you get current row time stamp, you perform your operation with last timestamp and reset previous timestamp with current one.